# Group items based on a formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I am creating an invoice using Crystal Reports & I want to group products which have the same `PRO_ID` into one line, for this I have created a `GROUP` and it works fine.

***Following is a sample of the data***

```
PRO_ID   NAME       ORDER_QTY
0001     Battery    2
0001     Battery    -6
0001     Battery    3
```

In the second line the quantity is a minus because of a returned item. I want to show the actually ordered items separately & returned items separately.

At the moment the report shows -1 for the `ORDER_QTY` because it just groups the Products based on the PRO_ID. How can I group these separately ?

Comment: how are you differentiating the returned items? excluding the -ve value display is there any other field that you are using?

Comment: no there is no other field. If the ORDER_QTY is less than 0 I consider it as a returned item.

Comment: check my answer and let me know incase any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

1. Keep `PRO_ID` as it is as the first group and then create a sub group `@group2` and write below code:

   ```
   if ORDER_QTY<0
   then "Returned"
   else "Actual"
   ```

Use `@group2` to group after `PRO_ID`.

Now place the all your fields in details.

hope this helps

Comment: Before writing the code what field do I need to select from the group expert wizard ?

Comment: select formula `@group2` in group expert

Comment: How do I add @group2 ?? sry I am new to CR

Comment: create a formula with name `group2` and there add the code... now when you go to `insert group` select formula `group2` so that the group will be created